# how can I add 19 in place of 00?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I forgot add 19 while inserting date now how can i add 19 in place of 00. How can I fix this?

```
select distinct to_char(hiredate ,'yyyy') as period
from emp
order by to_char(hiredate ,'yyyy');
```

/*check if first two digit are zero or not
if it is zero then replace with 19
if it is not zero then no change

output I am getting:

```
0090
0092
0093
0095
0096
0097
0098
0099
2000
```

expected output

```
1990
1992
1993
1995
1996
1997
1998
1999
2000
```

///

Comment: Your question seems to be very short and lacks definition but if I follow you correctly re-running the query (thereby replacing all the values with the correct ones) seem to be the easiest option? That way you don't have to write some fancy query to determine whether or not the first two characters are 00? Clearly your 'emp' table seems to hold the base data for this exercise?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to update the date? Use add_months as follows:

```
Update employee
   Set hiredate = add_months(hiredate, 1900*12)
 Where to_char(hiredate, 'cc') = '01'
```

Comment: why did u mention cc=01

Comment: It means first century. It will return all the dates having 00 as first two digits in your year

Comment: You can consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue so that this question is marked as resolved.